# angular - Listening on transcluded change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            template: '<p ng-transclude></p>',
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: true,
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I am trying to run code each time the transclusion content changes and the directive is rendered - I need the transcluded content.

Example algorithm I would like to run in this case is:

- count words of transcluded content.

I have tried `scope.$watch` in multiple forms but to no avail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use the jqlite included within Angular inside a watch expression function to accomplish this.  Below is code that watches the length of the transcluded element using jqLite (element.text().length).  The watch fires whenever the length of the element that this directive is attached to changes.

And the new length is passed in as `newValue` to the second function within the watch (since we return it from the first watch function).

```
  myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
     return {
        template: '<p ng-transclude></p>',
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

           scope.$watch(function () {
               return element.text().length;
           },

           function (newValue, oldValue) {
               console.log('New Length ', newValue);
          });
        }
      }
  });
```

I've got a working jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2erbF/6/

This addresses the word/letter count scenario.  But you could write a test on the `element.text()` itself if you needed it to fire on any changes- not just a length change.

Comment: Thank you so very much. All I had to do is watch a function!!! I can't believe I didn't try that. :)